# qemu -nographic no output in terminal

Tags: qemu

here I want to run dos in qemu without a GUI window.
I use `-nographic` option and it works fine on mac os.

here is some output of dos in terminal.

```
MSCDEX Version 2.23
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1986-1993. All rights reserved.
   Drive R: = Driver BANANA unit 0
A:\>
```

But on Ubuntu, there is simply no output, while it works fine without `-nographic`option.

The only difference I see may be that qemu of my mac is version 2.12.0, Ubuntu is 2.3.0.

So is there anyone know what happened here?

Thanks.

Another difference: I use Ubuntu via ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. It's  simply the version's fault.

upgrade to version 2.12.0 solved the problem.

And on my Ubuntu cloud server, there is no version 2.12.0 with apt-get. So I compiled it from source.

If anyone encounter this kind fo problem, you may try the new version.